# i want to pass text of clicked button when multiple button are there through ajax mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i am having multiple button and i want to get text of clicked button and fire ajax and call my controller method and pass text of clicked button as parameter to my controller method through ajax.

this is my view page:

```
<div class="skills-bar left">
 <input type="button" value="ipad" class="skill-link skill left  tested" id="btnSkill"> 
<input type="button" value="fan" class="skill-link skill left  tested" id="btnSkill"> 
                </div>
```

this is my jquery :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      var theButtons = $(".tested");
        $(theButtons).click(function () {
            var skill = $(this).val();
            alert(skill);
            var orderby = $('#orderby').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Search/ViewSpecificVendorDetailsbySkills",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'html',
                contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                cache: false,
                data: { "Skill": skill},
                    success: function (responce) {
                        $("#results").html(responce);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("error retrieving list");
                    }
                });

        });
  });
```

[image]

here when i click on Asp.net or ado.net or any skill i want to pass asp.net or ado.net as parameter to my controller with ajax but my controller method is not calling.

can anybody tell me whats the problem???

Comment: use unique id for btn elements you've same id for both buttons

Comment: Use `$(theButtons).on('click', function () {`

Comment: your code is correct `$(this).val()` will give you the btn unque value

Comment: Whats the signature of your controller method? Does it have parameter `string Skill`? Do you have any errors in he browser console?

Comment: can you show us  `ViewSpecificVendorDetailsbySkills` action method in `Search` controller

Comment: [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ViewSpecificVendorDetailsbySkills(string Skill)

Comment: actually what is happening is when first time i am clicking on any skill i am getting correct skill on my controller and i am getting my output.but when those newly generated records come naa as shown in picture and when i am clicking again on skill then nothing is happening

Comment: When you add elements dynamically you need to use event delegation. Use `$(someSelector).on('click', '.tested', function() {...` where `someSelector` is the nearest ancestor the is the container for **all** the buttons (and remove the `id` attributes from the buttons - its invalid html)

Comment: here someSelector means you are referring to my class name naa like this:$(.tested).on(----)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Use [delegated events](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**
>   Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

For dynamically created elements you should generate unique id, or remove the id and manage event actions only with class selectors.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.tested', function () {
        var skill = $(this).val();
        var orderby = $('#orderby').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Search/ViewSpecificVendorDetailsbySkills",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'html',
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                "Skill": skill
            }
        }).done(function (responce) {
            $("#results").html(responce);
        }).error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("error retrieving list");
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.tested', function () {:can you plz explain me this line.why you have written document??

Answer (score 0):

You can not use same id in same page please change it to class or create unique id